# Integrate Google translate in a TYPO3 11 Website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate, google-translation-api, typo3-11.x

our customer would like to integrate Google Translate on his Website. (The Website is a TYPO3 installation).
Is there a comfortable way to integrate Google translation on the fly on a website like a dropdown/select fields?

Thank you in advance,
Axel Peltzer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for: For translating content in the backend you can use the extension [Deepl Translate](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/wv_deepltranslate) The extension provides option to translate content element, and tca record texts to Deepl and Google supported languages.